# Should my edit have entered peer review?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer, specific-edit

While browing the late-answers review queue I was asked to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types/54568354#54568354).

The initial answer had no code formatting, and (as of time of this posting) no additional explanation about the given answer. Someone had already commented on the no explanation part, so I decided to make the edit of adding code formatting, and hoping the OP would add the requested information ( < 2k user, so my edit went over to peer review) and further leaving it at that. Since someone already asked for additional explanation.

Some time later I received the notification that my review got accepted, and went back to check on the answer to see if OP added the additional information.

Doing this, I noticed in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54568354/revisions) history a > 2k user added the code formatting as well (and better than mine at that). Looking at the timestamp of that revision this *direct edit* must have been done just around the same time I did my *peer reviewed edit*.

Shouldn't my peer review edit have been overruled by the direct edit from the 8k user who also edited it (making my edit to the post obsolete)? I feel like at least *my* edit shouldn't have been approved anymore, as it didn't improve the post anymore at all.

If I recall correctly I have gotten a message along the lines of "This post has already been edited/reviewed" before when making edits to review queue posts, urging me to look at the other edit first or even denying my edit. Did this just slip through a crack?

As far as I am aware peer review edits can not be rolled back by the editor. Re-editing the answer would do it no good either for such a small change would only add unnecessary clutter. And it certainly isn't worth creating a custom flag for either. Yet It feels wrong to have had my edit accepted.

Comment: The author of that post accepted your edit. Authors have a binding vote, so it was applied. I worry more about the one reviewer in the queue who also voted to accept. I rolled back your edit so the other edit is now visible.

Comment: I see @BDL . I did not know about authors having a binding vote. Thanks for rolling back the edit and the information.

Comment: "Shouldn't my peer review edit have been overruled by the direct edit from the 8k user who also edited it" - It would have been nice if the edit had not been submitted because the content was edited in between. But at this point when it comes to these kind of site features which have existed for ages, if they still have particular problems I assume it is really hard to fix them in a high-concurrency site such as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22140697) has a timestamp<sup>*</sup> of

```
2019-02-07 07:53:04Z
```

The edit by [adiga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082296/adiga) has a timestamp of

```
2019-02-07 07:52:47Z
```

i.e. 17 seconds before your edit was submitted.

It's entirely possible that you were both in the editing window at the same time - adiga's edit went through immediately because they are >2k; your edit required review so went through with a timestamp of

```
2019-02-07 09:55:31Z
```

or about two hours later.

Because your edit was applied *after* adiga's edit, the edits were merged so it *appears* as though your edit undid adiga's eidit and applied yours.

---

<sup>*</sup> You can get the timestamp for edits by hovering over the time in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54568354/revisions), e.g.:

[image]

Comment: And as a point of interest for those who may not know, generally *all* instances of a datetime on Stack Exchange sites can be hovered to reveal an exact timestamp via tooltip. On top of that, the "active" line at the top-right of question pages is also a link that will take you to the answer (or Q) that was most recently edited (active).